Separate module for activity, broadcast receiver and services?
I am completely new to multi-modular architecture. I am using jetpack compose. Asking flaws in my thinking.
Broadcast receiver and services don't contain ui logic, similar to activity. e can directly setuWp logic in presentation layer using the AppTheme block (it may not possible is xml approach, haven't used it in long time so i have no idea). Activities have rather different logic like splash activity may check user authorization or authentication. Depending if user is authorized, token expired, unauthorized or received an intent from external apps there may be different actions which isn't part of UI logic. Similarly MainActivity may deal differently according to message received from SplashActivity(or any other between the route) like setting the startDestination to settings page(message from SplashActivity).

Best practices for modularization are defining modules based on domain rather than UI/Service,
it means instead of having auth-ui and auth-service modules, you need to combine them, however, in this way, you may encounter the "circular dependency" challenge, To prevent this problem, you need to define a role for each module,
So, I recommend some roles here to help you organize modules,

if the module is a low-level module and it's shared across the
application, like providing caching or networking, you can consider
this is an infra/library module type.
if the module is shared across the application and has a common
business logic like auth module, remote config, or localization, you
can consider this as a plugin module, and there are top of the infra
module, which means they can use infra level module but it's not true in
vice versa.
if the module is just responsible for handling one job, like
onboarding pages or setting pages, you can consider this as a feature
module, they can use infra and plugins but they do not have
dependency on another module.
if the module is just for showing a complex page, for example, an
e-commerce application with a heavy home page, and each section of
the page comes from multiple modules, you need to create a
coordinator module to connect those features on one page, and it
gives you the power of isolation to develop and maintain each feature
separately and use on a shared page.
and the last you need to have one launcher module, this module is for
bundling your app and sending it to the store, another benefit is
that we you are in the development stage, you do not need to build
all parts of the application, and you create one debug module for
just testing your feature.

You can find more about modularization on the below links
Modularization at scale
Preparation for modularization
Android documentation
Video on youtube
